# Importing .sql file into my database inputs them out of order

Tags: sql, mysql

I am using phpadmin and I exported a .sql file to backup my database.  When I went to import the .sql file it imports the rows in the wrong order.  Is their anyway to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no order in the rows of a table. If you want any order you should always be using a `order by`. The result of `select` on the same table with `order by` will always be the same before backup and after the restore.

Comment: This is very true.  I have not worked very long with mysql and databases so I did not realize I could do it that way.  I need to do that.

Answer (score 2):

And how do you know they're in the wrong order? Do you mean that when you do a

```
select * from foo
```

for example, you're not seeing the records in the same order as before? That behavior is normal. If you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, the order is unspecified....

Comment: How would you specify an order for an import then?  Also, using php admin I can look at the mysql tables and after the import I realized that my auto increment field was all out of order.